# Access denied for user 'travis'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, centos, localhost, centos6

So I asked about this issue quite some time ago, but I was logged in under root and I was getting many biased comments saying that the script was trying to intentionally use root@localhost.

Anyways, I am on a different user, and this time it is

```
Access denied for user 'travis'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I am hoping I can get a bit different answers as to what I should do since I know for a fact its not the script.

This script has worked in the past with hostgator, but I now use a VPS running on Centos 6.

The script is fully Ioncubed to protect from ripping and re-modifying.

I tried using the root user with the root password for login since there is default root user made for each database, not even that login works.

If there is more info to provide, let me know. I really want to get this solved.

Comment: What if you try connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Basically you have to make sure that for user "travis" the password and hostname are correct! as Brad said, try 127.0.0.1

Comment: 127.0.0.1 makes no difference. But that is one of the default root users available. http://puu.sh/614SD.png I have the server set to be running on localhost in my httpd.conf file to. @iNDicator I have copied and pasted, and ENSURED it was typed correctly, no difference.

Comment: Ok so mysqld was not started. Since its not been started, I get apache@localhost instead.